# Applying 2 PDFs - for resource demand and also duration of resource use

Tags: distributions

If I have a (lets say) kayak rental business which is open 24/7 and has no hourly variation in the parameters outlined below.

1. The number of customers approaching the stall to rent a kayak each hour follows a Poisson distribution, say with a λ = 0.5
2. The duration of rental (time before the customer returns the kayak) follows a right skewed distribution of some kind - lets say log normal (working in hours as our unit of time):
   μ = ln(2) and σ = ln(1.5)

What is the CDF for the number of kayaks rented out at a given moment in time? If this is not solvable, how might I approximate a solution or find an alternative approach? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume instead an exponential distribution of rental times, then there are exact solutions from the theory of the $M/M/\infty$ [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/%E2%88%9E_queue).

In your example, you might take the exponential distribution with scale parameter $\beta = \exp(\ln(2)+\ln(1.5)^2/2)$, so that the kayak rental times have the same mean as in the lognormal example. Meanwhile your Poisson distribution has $\lambda = 1/2$.

Then the probability of having $j$ kayaks rented out after $t$ hours is $e^{-u}u^j/j!$ where $u=\lambda\beta(1-e^{-t/\beta})$.